# combo box on form is not getting populated when used with DNS in URL and gets populated when used with IP address in URL

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, url, dns

I have a drop down on my form(JSP page) which will be visible when I select a particular value from another drop down. It is working fine when I use URL for the page with IP address and port, but it does not works when I use URL with DNS.

When used with DNS the dependent drop down field does not gets populated on the form. It's really strange and I have not came across such scenario before. Please provide any solution if you have

Thanks in advance.